# Eclipse error: java was started but returned exit code=1

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently installed the new java 1.8.0_40 and now I get this error when starting eclipse:
[image]
[image]

This is my eclipse.ini.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-

Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-vm  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\bin
```

Comment: Are you running a 64 bit Eclipse build on a 32 bit JVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this occurs if your eclipse version is 32 bit and JVM is 64 bit or vice versa. Try installing either a new version of eclipse or the other version of java 1.8 for the matching version on your machine and it should work.